# Solve a system of equations with MATLAB

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, matlab

I'm trying to solve a system of equations with MATLAB (R2012b):

```
syms w1 w2 x1 x2 y1 y2
eqns = [w1 + w2 == 1;
    1/6 == 1/2 * (w1 * x1 + w2 * x2);
    1/6 == 1/2 * (w1 * y1 + w2 * y2);
    1/24 == 1/2 * (w1 * x1 * y1 + w2 * x2 * y2);
    1/24 == 1/2 * (w1 * x1^2 + w2 * x2^2);
    1/24 == 1/2 * (w1 * y1^2 + w2 * y2^2)];
vars = [w1 w2 x1 x2 y1 y2];

[solv, solu] = solve(eqns, vars)
```

The code above yields the warning:

> 12 equations in 6 variables. Explicit solution could not be found.

What's going on? `eqns` contains 6, not 12, equations and we have 6 variables.

Comment: Under the circumstances, it would not surprise me if internally the program was performing a Galois theory type calculation and finding that the relevant Galois group is not solvable. Try using fsolve instead.

Comment: @Ian How can I solve the problem with `fsolve`?

Comment: In principle, you just define the equations again, but now in a function that takes in a vector x of length 6 and returns a vector of length 6, whose components are the residuals of your equations. So for example the first component could be x(1)+x(2)-1. This did not work with random initial guesses, though.

Comment: The result of your system consist $6$ elements which you are trying to output to a vector of $2$ elements. Change the last line to be 'S = solve(eqns,vars);'. Then you can get the value of $w_1$ with 'S.w1'.

Comment: @Galc127 That doesn't fix anything, the problem is that solve fails to return anything at all. Indeed you can try just calling solve(eqns,vars) without assigning to anything, it will fail.

Comment: @0xbadf00d You may need to play with fsolve options a bit, I got an answer that it claims is after convergence, but the residuals are not negligible (the norm of the residual vector is something like 0.02). So you might want to lower the convergence tolerance.

Comment: @Ian, I checked and it does work. using 'solve' I got the solution $$(w1,w2, x1,x2,y1,y2)=\left(\frac{4}{3},-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},0,\frac{1}{4},0\right)$$

Comment: @Galc127 You must be running a different version of Matlab from me, because when I copy the code in the OP and just change the output parameters of solve to a single variable, I get the same error as 0xbadf00d. I'm using R2013b.

Comment: @Ian, I am running R2016a, it could be the reason...

Comment: @Ian I've tried to use `fsolve` and it yielded `w1 = w2= 0.5025` which obviously doesn't satisfy the first equation. That's probably a problem with some of the default tolerances. Do you know how I can change them and to what I should change them?

Comment: @0xbadf00d You can make a structure using the GUI that is spawned when you call the function optimtool. Then you can pass this function directly into fsolve, as the only argument. However, it seems like this problem might be a bit difficult for fsolve's algorithm, because it seems to be naturally pulled towards roughly $(0.5,0.5,0.317,0.317,0.317)$ for certain ostensibly reasonable initial guesses, but I don't think there is even a solution near that point.

Comment: @Ian Suppose I've saved the function into a file `f.m`. What do I need to specify in the "objective function" textbox?

Comment: I think you want @f. You don't need that @ if you define the function inline, by f=@(x) ... syntax.

Comment: If you can't use the solution from @Galc127 above, I recommend reading the documentation for `solve` (`doc solve` in your Command Window) for your version of Matlab (not the online one). In older versions of Matlab you cannot stick all of your equations and variables in an array (`[...]`), but must rather separate them with commas.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, Maple has no trouble finding the solution:

```
eqns:= [w1 + w2 = 1,
    1/6 = 1/2 * (w1 * x1 + w2 * x2),
    1/6 = 1/2 * (w1 * y1 + w2 * y2),
    1/24 = 1/2 * (w1 * x1 * y1 + w2 * x2 * y2),
    1/24 = 1/2 * (w1 * x1^2 + w2 * x2^2),
    1/24 = 1/2 * (w1 * y1^2 + w2 * y2^2)]:
vars := [w1, w2, x1, x2, y1, y2]:
solve(eqns, vars);
```

$${\it w1}={\frac {4 (9\,{{\it y2}}^{2}-6\,{\it y2}+1)}{3(12\,{{\it y2}
}^{2}-8\,{\it y2}+1)}},\; {\it w2}= \frac{-1}{ 36\,{{\it y2}}^{2}-24\,{\it y2
}+3 },\; {\it x1}={\frac {4\,{\it y2}-1}{4(3\,{\it y2}-1)}}
, \\{\it x2}={\it y2},\; {\it y1}=-{\frac {-4\,{\it y2}+1}{12\,{\it y2}-4}},
\;{\it y2}={\it y2}
$$

Comment: Could you please add the code you've used to obtain the solution with Maple? (And didn't you said something like "that's not a problem of Matlab, but ..."? I wasn't fast enough to read it, before you've edited your post.)

Comment: I did delete that remark, because I realized I wasn't sure it wasn't a syntax mistake in the Matlab command.